# Bootstrap Grid System aligning issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to shift my **select** under drivers license number to the left to start under the D in drivers license number. So that they line up with the selects above it. 
[image]
But still keeping this select small since there is only 2 letters for states in the drop down.

```
<div class="row">           
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="birthmonth_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Date of birth:</label>
            <cfinclude template="../ddl/birthmonth.cfm">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <cfinclude template="../ddl/birthday.cfm">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <cfinclude template="../ddl/birthyear.cfm">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Sex:</label>
            <cfinclude template="../ddl/gender.cfm">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="driverlicense_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" class="labelspace">Driver license number:</label>
            <cfoutput>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <cfinclude template="../ddl/dlstates.cfm">  <!--- If you need to re-insert into HTML and not use as include, then you have to correct the file location i.e(../../../) --->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>&nbsp;</label><cfinclude template="../includes/tooltip.cfm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="driverlicense_#Add#" id="driverlicense_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" maxlength="50" required="yes" value="#session.checkout.info["driverlicense_" & Add]#" />
            </cfoutput>
            <span id="result_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I am trying to bring the input (to the right) closer so that they are not so far apart.

I have tried many different combinations and for some reason have not been able to figure out this grid system with why the select starts indented and how to move the input to the right of the select closer even after reading and rereading the docs.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/m6hqdr91/1/

Comment: it is hard to understand with the colfusion codes but when i fiddle it with simple bootstrap form elements it looks all right. can you fiddle it and update the question? there must been something else that interfering it.

Comment: Well, we can't see your css. From just looking at your html, it looks like you have col-lg-12 assigned to that div and that wraps the state dropdown. Col-lg-12 has padding left 15px and right declared in the bootstrap.css.

Comment: We can't really do anything without having your template files in here as well. Please include those for us.

Comment: @Cromwell https://jsfiddle.net/m6hqdr91/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `col-lg-12` inside a `form-group` (wrapping the `input`) because it is giving an extra `padding` on the left and right but the label doesn't have any `padding` on it. Like:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="labelspace">Driver license number:</label>
  <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="labelspace">Driver license number:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Select</option></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a look at the example snippet below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h4>With <code>col-xs-12</code> class (old code)</h4>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="labelspace">Driver license number:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Select</option></select>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<hr>

<h4>Without class (updated code)</h4>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="labelspace col-xs-12">Driver license number:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you a bunch that really helped explain things to me

Comment: Its my pleasure @DavidBrierton

Comment: how would you choose the size of just the select below it though if you cannot put it inside the form-group?

Comment: @DavidBrierton If you are using `col-lg-12` on `input`, then use it on the `label` as well, like: `<label class="col-lg-12" for="">`, Hope you get it.

Comment: How do I adjust sizes of the selects if they are chosen by the label since i cant put them inside a form-group

Comment: the problem is i want the entire label on one line but the select smaller since it only has two letters in the select

Comment: when i shorten the select it splits the label and drops part down just didnt know how to split the two to control both sizes

Comment: @DavidBrierton I've updated my code snippet in my answer, have a look. I've given full width to label and half of it to select.